# ViewScoped for CDI in JSF2.2 lifeCycle

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi, view-scope

I am trying to use @ViewScoped in javax.faces.view.ViewScoped with the @Named annotation, but for some reason every time I invoke my action to update part of my page, my bean instantiate again and I don't get the expected result! which if I use @ManagedBean and viewScoped(javax.faces.beans.ViewScoped), it's functioning fine.

Another question is why the bean get instantiated more than one time? Is it because of the application server behaviour??

Here is my xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"></p:growl>
    <p:fieldset legend="Search Criteria" toggleable="true"
        toggleSpeed="100">
        <p:panelGrid>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputLabel for="id" value="User Id">  </p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText id="id" value="#{test.id}"> </p:inputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputLabel for="username"  value="Username"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText id="username" value="# {test.name}"></p:inputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:outputLabel for="pass" value="Password"></p:outputLabel>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputText id="pass" value="#{test.password}"></p:inputText>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column></p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{test.searchAction}"
                        update="table">

                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>

        </p:panelGrid>

    </p:fieldset>
    <p:fieldset legend="Search Result">
        <p:dataTable id="table" paginator="true" rows="20"
            value="#{test.users}" selectionMode="single" var="user"
            selection="#{test.user}" rowKey="#{user.userId}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{test.selectRow}"
                oncomplete="dialog.show();" update=":form:growl  :grid"></p:ajax>
            <p:column headerText="User ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.userId}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Username">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.userName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Password">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.userPassword}" />
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Proceed" update=":grid"
                    oncomplete="dialog.show();"> </p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>

        </p:dataTable>

    </p:fieldset>

</h:form>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog" appendToBody="true">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="grid">
        #{test.user.userId}
        <p:spacer></p:spacer>
        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{test.saveAction}">
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>


</h:body>
</html>
```

and here is my back bean:

```
package com.meysam.app.mypocekt.managedbean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

import com.meysam.app.mypocket.jpa.User;

@Named(value = "test")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1275620800039726757L;
private User user;
private String name;
private Long id;
private String password;
private List<User> users;

public TestBean() {
    users = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Constructor");
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("postConstruct");
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public String searchAction() {
    System.out.println("search Action");
    for (int i = 20; i < 40; i++) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(new Long(i));
        user.setUserName("MyName" + i);
        user.setUserPassword("password" + i);
        users.add(user);
    }
    return null;
}

public String saveAction() {
    System.out.println("next");
    return "next?faces-redirect=true";
}

public void selectRow(SelectEvent event) {

    // User user = (User) event.getObject();
    System.out.println("User: " + user.getUserName());
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("User: " + user.getUserName());
    System.out.println("selected event" + user.getUserName());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

and this is my console result when I refresh the page and then click search button:

```
15:43:34,667 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) Constructor

15:43:34,668 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) postConstruct

15:43:34,673 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) Constructor

15:43:34,673 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) postConstruct

15:43:34,674 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) Constructor

15:43:34,674 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) postConstruct

15:43:34,676 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) Constructor

15:43:34,676 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) postConstruct

15:43:34,677 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) Constructor

15:43:34,677 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) postConstruct

15:43:34,678 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) Constructor

15:43:34,678 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) postConstruct

15:43:34,679 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) Constructor

15:43:34,680 INFO  [stdout] (default task-32) postConstruct

15:43:39,851 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,852 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,852 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,853 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,853 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,853 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,854 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,854 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,855 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,855 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,855 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,856 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,856 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,856 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,857 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,857 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,857 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,857 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,858 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,858 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,858 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,859 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,859 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,859 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,860 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,860 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,861 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,861 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,861 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,862 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,862 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,862 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,863 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,863 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,863 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,863 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,864 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,864 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,864 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,864 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,865 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,865 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,865 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) search Action

15:43:39,872 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,872 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,872 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,873 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,873 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,874 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,874 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,874 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct

15:43:39,876 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) Constructor

15:43:39,876 INFO  [stdout] (default task-33) postConstruct
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The two annotations (CDI and JSF) don't work together. You'd need to write an extension or use CODI or Apache DeltaSpike to bridge gap.

JSF 2.0 (where the ViewScope annotations comes from) did not have any CDI integration.

Comment: Actually not true, it's `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` which comes with JSF 2.2 so it really should be CDI compatible

Comment: I hadn't noticed the package change in the code above. I'm SOOO glad they kept the same name and just changed the package, thus creating even more of headache for us *sigh*

Comment: I am using JSF 2.2, So basically, I think CDI viewScope is already provided in JSF 2.2!